# How to detect and remove lines above data set while reading from csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
name: john
date modified: 2018-09
from: jane
colum1 column2 column3
data    data    data
```

Is there any function I can apply that would strip off any lines before the tabular data begins when reading from csv? currently the lines above `column` look like strange characters when I read them in.

New table should look like this:

```
colum1 column2 column3
data    data    data
```

Comment: You can skip the rows while reading them.https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: is there anyway I can programmatically skip the lines? I have many files with these sort of headers and not with fixed length.

Comment: Well does the first line you want to keep always start with `'column1'`? Or does the last line of the header that you want to skip always end with `'from:'`?

Comment: @ALollz thats the thing the documents are not standardized so I dont know the ending of the header or the column names. I was thinking maybe there would be an inbuilt function that detects where the tabular data columns begin

Comment: I don't think there is a perfect way. In my experience the pandas parser will use the 0th row (after skiprows) as the header and the basis for tokenizing the Data. You can try to have it automatically figure out what you want, but for instance, it will parse the file perfectly well with `from: jane` as the header column, which will make your first two columns a multiIndex. You really need to come up with some algorithmic pattern if you hope to do this properly without any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
from io import StringIO
with open('filename.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
s = StringIO(''.join((l for l in lines if ':' not in l)))
pd.read_csv(s)
```

Alternatively:

```
with open('filename.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
skip_rows_idx = [i for i, l in enumerate(lines) if ':' in l]
pd.read_csv('filename.csv', skiprows=skip_rows_idx)
```

If there are no colons in the header, then one could adapt the above code (first example) to drop first lines like this:

```
import itertools
s = StringIO(''.join(itertools.dropwhile(lambda l: ':' in l, lines)))
```

(assuming there are no "bad" lines *after* the header).

Comment: Lets hope there are no timestamps in the csv :D

Comment: @ALollz Agree. This is my best guess based on the information provided.

Comment: @AGNGazer thank you for the example, there will be timestamps.

Comment: @ALollz If the docs are in fixed format, it can be simply replaced with the number of prefix rows.

Comment: @RustyShackleford The method outlined here just shows how to work around this limitation in pandas. It can be adapted to other criterions. However, you do not provide other information. For example, how would you expect a function to know when to skip a row?

Comment: Well, there probably won’t be a colon in the colum headers, so could perhaps count the lines until the first without a colon? (Assuming all bad headed lines have a colon)

Comment: @AGNGazer this gives me a good framework to work out the issues such as when to skip lines.

Comment: @RustyShackleford See my latest edit. It shows how to skip first lines with `':'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    counter=0
    for row in reader:
        if(''.join(row).startswith('colum1')):
            starting_row=counter # get the valid row programatically
        counter+=1
        break
pd.read_csv('test.csv',skiprows=starting_row) # skip previous rows
```